# Why am I getting null values when using gson to parse a json object in android studio?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, gson

I am reading in the following JSON and using GSON to convert it to an object which I can then use to access the properties of said object to help display the images in my app.

However one of the field I want to use, imageURL, is returning null values. Looking at the json (link below) we can clearly see that it is not null.

https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/youtube/home_feed

I have used the debugger to demonstrate the null value I am getting for each imageURL:

[Debugger output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoh7h.png)

So the object is giving me null values for the imageURL but the link is not. What is going on?

Here is the function I wrote to fetch and parse the JSON object:

```
private fun fetchJson() {
        println("Attempting to fetch JSON")

        val url = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/youtube/home_feed"
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                println(body)

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeed::class.java)

                runOnUiThread {
                    recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapter(homeFeed)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("failed to execute request")
            }
        }
         )

    }
```

My HomeFeed class is like this:

```
class HomeFeed(val videos: List<Video>)

class Video(val id: Int, val name: String, val link: String, val imageURL: String, numberOfViews: Int,
            val channel: Channel)

class Channel(val name: String, val profileImageUrl: String)
```

I believe this should be detailed enough but if anymore info is needed please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add your model of your object ...

Comment: I have just added that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this object, you should use the same name for the vals, "imageUrl" instead of "imageURL":

```
data class HomeFeed(
    val user: User,
    val videos: List<Video>
)

data class User(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val username: String
)

data class Video(
    val channel: Channel,
    val id: Int,
    val imageUrl: String,
    val link: String,
    val name: String,
    val numberOfViews: Int
)

data class Channel(
    val name: String,
    val numberOfSubscribers: Int,
    val profileImageUrl: String
)
```

Comment: I spent an hour trying to fix this.....and it is just a typo :( Thanks for the help!